# Error when POSTing to react app after SAML auth

Tags: reactjs, heroku, saml, auth0

Completely stumped on an issue I'm dealing with, and I feel like I've looked everywhere, just can't wrap my head around it.

I've got an app that's built as follows:

- React frontend, built using Create React App
- A separate API, running on a separate server, which the frontend interacts with via RESTful calls
- Auth0 handling auth, using a SAML connection. Authentication is successful against the SAML connection.
- App is hosted on Heroku, and uses the @mars/create-react-app buildback.

The issue I'm experiencing is that after the SAML authentication, there is a redirect back to my app as a POST. My app doesn't know what to do with said POST, and I'm unsure why.

The ideal scenario I'm looking for is:

- User visits `domain.com/login`
- User is redirected to SAML IdP, which asks for login
- User logs in with IdP, and is sent back to my app, preferably just to the path `/explorer`. This should all be straight GET.

I'm happy to post any code related, but unsure what would be the most helpful. Despite me having set the SAML protocol binding to "redirect" on Auth0, it continues to post back to my app. I might simply be misunderstanding that piece, however.

Again, happy to post whatever code would help, just unsure what's most useful to see. Like I said, it seems that auth is working, just that after the authentication, there's a POST back to my root, and my app has zero clue what to do with it. There is no nginx config to speak of.

Thanks for any tips or hints about where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Quick followup. Solved this (I think) by spinning up a simple Express server to serve the React app with, and routed `POST /` to `index.html`, which seems to have worked for now.